# Integral of a function times a Fourier transform is zero

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

This comes from Hall's *Quantum Theory for Mathematicians*, Lemma 9.33. I'm having trouble with one of the arguments in the proof. I believe it boils down to the following:

Let $f\colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\int f(x) \hat g(x) \,\mathrm{d}x = 0$ for all smooth $g$ with compact support, where $\hat g$ denotes the Fourier transform of $g$. I then want to show that $f = 0$. In the proof $f$ is a difference of an $L^2$-function and an $L^2$-function times a coordinate function.

Hall cites the Stone-Weierstrass theorem and the theorem about density of continuous functions with compact support in $L^p$, but he's not super clear. (He also starts talking about the functions as if they are defined on $\mathbb{R}$, so I don't know what is going on.)

Also, do feel free to change the title to something more descriptive, I wasn't sure how to title my question.

[image: Part 1]

[image: Part 2]

Comment: It might be helpful to attach a figure of the proof in question, as well.

Comment: @cmk Is it okay to reproduce the whole proof here?

Comment: That would also be perfectly good!

Comment: @cmk I have added some screenshots.

Comment: It is all mixed up. The proof itself is ambivalent as to whether $\chi\in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ , thus appearing in two places in the proof, or maybe $\chi\in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$, as it appears on a third occasion. Poorly written, to be sure, but if you change $\mathbb{R}$ consistently to $\mathbb{R}^n$, and the interval $[a,b]$ to a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, the proof seems to just about be valid.

Comment: @uniquesolution So the space of smooth functions with support in a compact $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is dense in $L^2(K)$. Could you elaborate on exactly why the claim follows from this? Since it is $\hat \chi$ and not $\chi$ that appears in the integrands, I'm not quite sure how to proceed.

Comment: @DannyHansen -- The street wisdom is this: if some functional operating on the Fourier transforms of all test functions (in this case these would be the $\chi$'s) satisfies something, then that something holds in general. I know it is a bit vague, but that's what he had in mind, I suppose.

Comment: @uniquesolution Hmm, seems a bit quick compared to the rest of the book. In an appendix he cites this result for all $\chi \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$, but not for their Fourier transforms. Do you know more concretely what sort of argument one would need to tie things together?

Comment: @cmk The proof is typeset in $\rm\LaTeX$, so it should be typed out and cited, because the [SE network discourage text-images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155601/259305).

Answer (score 3):

Since $g\mapsto \hat g:L^2(\mathbb R^n)\to L^2(\mathbb R^n)$ is an isometric isomorphism, we can choose an approximate identity $(\hat \phi_n).$ Now $\phi_n$ is smooth for each integer $n$ and  there are compactly supported smooth functions $(\psi_{jn})$ such that $\|\psi_{jn}-\phi_n\|\to 0$ and so $\|\widehat{\psi_{jn}-\phi_n}\|=\|\hat\psi_{jn}-\hat\phi_n\|\to 0$ as well. Then,

$\tag1 \|\hat\psi_{jn}*f-f\|\le \|\hat \psi_{jn}*f-\hat \phi_n*f\|+\|\hat \phi_n*f-f\|.$

We have, by Cauchy-Schwarz,

$\|\hat \psi_{jn}*f-\hat \phi_n*f\|\le \|\hat \psi_{jn}-\hat \phi_n\|\cdot \|f\|$ and so $\|\hat \psi_{jn}*f-\hat \phi_n*f\|<\epsilon$ if $j$ is large enough. On the other hand, $\|\hat \phi_n*f-f\|<\epsilon$ if $n$ is large enough, because $(\hat\phi_n)$ is an approximate identity.

But $\hat \psi_{jn}*f(x)=\int \hat \psi_{jn}(x-y)f(y)dy=0$ by hypothesis and so $(1)$ becomes

$\tag2 \|f\|\le \|\hat \psi_{jn}*f-\hat \phi_n*f\|+\|\hat \phi_n*f-f\|<2\epsilon.$

It follows that $f=0$ almost everywhere.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. A couple of questions, because I've never heard of approximate identities before (but I just looked them up): We need a function $\phi$ so that $\hat\phi \in L^1$, which I guess is no problem. But from looking up the theorems in Folland, don't we need $f \in L^p$? Also, aren't you assuming that $\lVert f \rVert$ is finite?

Comment: The norm $\|\cdot\|$ I am using is the $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$ norm, because it looks like that is what Hall is saying (although his proof is confusing). The formula concerning approximate identites we are using is with $p=2. f$ is the difference of two $L^2$ functions, so it is $L^2,$ right? It is $not$ claimed that $f\in L^1$ nor is this necessary.  I should have noted at the beginning that since $g$  is $L^2$, and supported in the compact set $K$ then it is also $L^1$ (Cauchy Schwarz:  $\|f\chi_K\|_1 \leq \|f\|_2\|\chi_R\|_2 = (2m(K))^{1/2}\|f\|_2 < \infty$) so the Plancherel theorem applies.

Comment: I don't think we can assume that $f$ is the difference of two $L^2$ functions. In the proof, $\hat \phi$ is certainly, but we want to show that $i k_j \hat\psi$ is a well, hence we want to show that $f = 0$.

Comment: I believe the proof goes though if $f\in L^p$ in general. Replace Cauchy-Schwarz by Holder for the first term and then for the second,  note that for any approximate identity we have $\|\phi*f-f\|_p\to 0.$ Then you get $\int |f|^p=0$ and $f$ is $0$ a.e. If $f$ is not known to lie in any $L^p$  I do not see how to prove the claim.